# MYSQL order large database by decimal 10,10

Tags: mysql

I have about 25 million rows containing 0.183463545, 0.183423545, 0.183443545, 0.183443445, 0.183447545 and so on.

I need to order these however it currently takes around 20 seconds. Any way to speed it up? AFAIK, I have my index put it place correctly.

Thank you!

```
SELECT `a`.`float_val`,
   `a`.`num_id`,
   `b`.`userID`,
   `c`.`img`,
   `c`.`username`,
   `b`.`img`,
   `d`.`exterior`
FROM `a`
INNER JOIN `b` ON `b`.`num_id` = `a`.`num_id`
INNER JOIN `d` ON `d`.`id` = `b`.`item`
INNER JOIN `c` ON `c`.`userID` = `b`.`userID`
WHERE `float_val` IS NOT NULL
AND `float_val` BETWEEN 0 AND 1
AND `username` = 'ABC'
ORDER BY `float_val` LIMIT 100
```

Index is on `float_val`, `num_id`, `userID`

```
CREATE TABLE `float` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`num_id` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`float_val` decimal(10,10) DEFAULT NULL,
`userID` char(17) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_checked` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`index10` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `floatID` (`num_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `num_id` (`num_id`,`userID`),
KEY `userID` (`userID`),
KEY `float_val` (`float_val`),
KEY `last_checked` (`last_checked`),
KEY `index10` (`index10`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25750916 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Post your schema, including indexes and the exact query you are having your problem with.

Comment: What are you doing with the results?  Returning 25 million rows is a lot of data.

Comment: working on posting the information requested.
@GordonLinoff there is a limit of 100 rows but it still takes 20 secs.

Comment: but could you post your table definition (schema  - `CREATE TABLE` statement)

Comment: Can you post the table declares. Looking at that you have an index on float_val that will be useful for the sort, but not a useful index for the join to table b (ie, on num_id)

Comment: MySQL will only use 1 of those indexes on that table in that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** to reflect table definitions shown.

Start by doing a query to obtain the lowest `float_val` rows from table `a`.

```
       SELECT a.id
         FROM a
         INNER JOIN b ON b.num_id = a.num_id
         INNER JOIN d ON d.id = b.item
         INNER JOIN c ON c.userID = b.userID
         WHERE c.username = 'ABC'
           AND a.float_val BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0
         ORDER BY a.float_val
        LIMIT 100
```

If you have an index on `a(float_val,num_id)`, and another on `c.username` this will be reasonably fast. It will spit out the `id` values for the rows of `a` that are candidates for your query. (If you're using MyISAM, you need an index on `a(float_val, num_id, id)`.  By the way, the BETWEEN clause also implies IS NOT NULL.

Then use that as a subquery to complete your query, as follows.

```
SELECT a.float_val,
   a.num_id,
   b.userID,
   c.img,
   c.username,
   b.img,
   d.exterior
FROM a
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT a.id
         FROM a
         INNER JOIN b ON b.num_id = a.num_id
         INNER JOIN d ON d.id = b.item
         INNER JOIN c ON c.userID = b.userID
         WHERE c.username = 'ABC'
           AND a.float_val BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0
         ORDER BY a.float_val
        LIMIT 100
     ) q ON a.ID = q.id
INNER JOIN b ON b.num_id = a.num_id
INNER JOIN d ON d.id = b.item
INNER JOIN c ON c.userID = b.userID
WHERE c.username = 'ABC'
  AND a.float_val BETWEEN 0.0 AND 1.0
ORDER BY a.float_val  LIMIT 100
```

This kind of query contains a *deferred join.* That dramatically reduces the number of rows of the full query that need to be subjected to `ORDER BY ... LIMIT`. Without the deferred join, your original query sorts an enormous mess of quite long rows just to discard all but the first hundred of them. That's why it takes so long.

This should help. The next optimization step is to look at the `EXPLAIN` output from this query and the exact definitions of your tables.

*Pro tip*: In queries of this complexity, always qualify column names with table names or aliases. That is, use `a.float_val` throughout, rather than just `float_val`. This is a kindness to the next person to look at the query.